# Calling a javascript function from a textbox in winforms

Tags: javascript, winforms, function, textbox

I have textbox in one of my forms and i want to call a javascript function from a javascript file...

My code is

```
    this.txtbox.Text = "";
    this.txtbox.Location = new Point(10, 20);
    this.txtbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
    this.txtbox.Multiline = true;
    this.Controls.Add(txtbox);
    this.txtbox1.Text = "";
    this.txtbox1.Location = new Point(220,100);
    this.txtbox1.Size  = new System.Drawing.Size(100,100);
    this.Controls.Add(txtbox1);
```

And my javascript.js file contains a function

```
function alertMsgLength() {
   alert("a");
}
```

How to call alertMsgLength() function  to my textbox,

```
this.txtbox.OnKeyPress=?
this.txtbox.OnKeyDown=?
```

Any suggestion...

Comment: You've tagged your question 'winforms' but your JavaScript looks like it's expecting a web page. Can you clarify your environment? WCF or...?

Comment: @T.J now its a simple javascript function... How to call it in my textbox...

Comment: My question still stands, what environment? Is it a standalone Windows forms application? A web-based application? The answer *kind of depends* on it.

Comment: @T.J C# windows application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call JavaScript function from C# WinForms application, you will have to host Scripting runtime within your application. Microsoft provides interfaces that will allow you to execute Windows Scripting Engine inside your application and expose your controls to it. It's not an easy thing to do, and I would not suggest doing it, unless you have a very good reason (like writing a very large, customizable application, that you want to provide API for users to change the behaviors, etc.). Take a look at those links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/t9d4xf28(VS.85).aspx 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csscriptengine.aspx

P.S. If you just need to call some JavaScript function from your textbox, I would highly recommend converting that JavaScript to C#. C# can do everything scripting languages can do better.